# Unable to show div content for onmouseover event, in expected area in IE 11, for only table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to show some links, on mouseover, on another link. I have few links aligned in table. For each of the links in the rows, I need to show a div with content near the link on which I mouse over, and being able to select/click them.

This is working fine in other browsers like firefox.

When I directly open the HTML file in IE11 browser, it is working fine, but when I run the file on a tomcat server, it is not.
However it does work outside of the table element.

Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dropdown-contentshow {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-contenthide {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-contentshow {
            display: block;

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-contenthide {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-contentshow a {
            padding: 3px 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-contentshow a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-contentshow {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<br>
<br>
<center> Testing for MouseOver</center>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tr onmouseover="document.getElementById('hi').className='dropdown-contentshow';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('hi').className='dropdown-contenthide';">
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a onmouseover="document.getElementById('hi').className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                   onmouseout="document.getElementById('hi').className='dropdown-contenthide';" class="dropbtn"
                   href="#">Test Cases Report </a>
                <div id="hi" class="dropdown-contenthide" onmouseover="this.className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                     onmouseout="this.className='dropdown-contenthide';"><!--sravani-->
                    <a target="_blank" id="java" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo1.html"> Java</a>
                    <a target="_blank" id="html" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo2.html"> HTML</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a onmouseover="document.getElementById('hi1').className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                   onmouseout="document.getElementById('hi1').className='dropdown-contenthide';" class="dropbtn"
                   href="#"> Setups Report </a>
                <div id="hi1" class="dropdown-contenthide" onmouseover="this.className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                     onmouseout="this.className='dropdown-contenthide';"><!--sravani-->
                    <a target="_blank" id="java" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo1.html"> Java</a>
                    <a target="_blank" id="html" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo2.html"> HTML</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a onmouseover="document.getElementById('hi2').className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                   onmouseout="document.getElementById('hi2').className='dropdown-contenthide';" class="dropbtn"
                   href="#">My Tasks Report </a>
                <div id="hi2" class="dropdown-contenthide" onmouseover="this.className='dropdown-contentshow';"
                     onmouseout="this.className='dropdown-contenthide';"><!--sravani-->
                    <a target="_blank" id="java" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo1.html"> Java</a>
                    <a target="_blank" id="html" href="http://syapamanu:8080/tooltip/demo2.html"> HTML</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Working case :
[image]

Not working case:

[image]

Comment: Start by [validating your HTML](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I see a missing closing bracket in your css for `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-contentshow` selector. No `<body>` section in HTML may also cause some issues

Comment: @tshimkus,thank you ,even I corrected it, I could not get the dropdown content in the expected area.i.e, below the mouseovered link.radher showing at side of the link.

Comment: @mplungjan, tq for the link,it is very helpful.